# What do I need to create an SSH tunnel to a local network service running on my remote host?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, ssh-tunneling

I would like to connect a virtualbox computer to a local service on a remote computer. I can connect to local services, but the remote one, I have a problem because on the destination, the service runs in a local LAN.

Here is a graphic of the 3 computer and two interfaces on the 3rd computer. I want to connect to 10.0.0.8:200 since the service I want to connect to only runs on that local network on the remote computer.

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|  VirtualBox        |
|  192.168.11.11:200 |
|                    |
+-----+--------------+
      |
      v
+--------------------+
|                    |
|  Local Computer    |
|  192.168.11.41:200 |
|                    |
+-----+--------------+
      |
      v
+--------------------+
|                    |
|  Remote Computer   |
|  8.8.8.8           |    <- I can connect here
|                    |
|  10.0.0.8:200      |    <- how do I connect here?
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

I'm able to open a tunnel between Local Computer and Remote Computer, but that does not give me a way to connect to the service on local network 10.0.0.8.

What I have so far is the SSH tunnel between the Local Computer and the Remote Computer. I can otherwise connect between the VirtualBox and Local Computer (I have a bridged network setup with works as expected.)

```
ssh -L 200:8.8.8.8:200 example.com
```

So what I'm missing is a connection between 8.8.8.8 and 10.0.0.8. How do I create a tunnel/proxy between the two which makes service on 10.0.0.8:200 available to my Local Computer?

Comment: Have you tried running `ssh -L 200:10.0.0.8:200 8.8.8.8` on your local computer? That should create a tunnel from your local computer to the service via the remote computer. You should then be able to access that service from your VM via the host machine (local computer).

Comment: Isn't 8.8.8.8 Google's DNS server?

Comment: @DavidDai I did not want to disclose my IP. :-)

Comment: Ok I'm assuming 8.8.8.8 is the same as example.com. Then what you need to do is simply `ssh -L 200:10.0.0.8:200 example.com`. That means connections to localhost:200 will be forwarded to `10.0.0.8:200` on the remote host, which is where your program listens for connection.

Comment: @DavidDai So I tried that, as igal and you are saying I should do and I get a "Connection Refused" immediately. As if my local network (ssh client) did not want to forward anything. Yet I see the port open when I do `netstat`. Oh, nevermind, it puts it on the localhost, not my local LAN... okay.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to `localhost:200` or `your-local-ip:200`? If the latter, you may want to try `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:200:10.0.0.8:200 example.com`.

Comment: Okay! That worked! Yes, I need the local-ip so I can connect from my VirtualBox.Feel free to write an answer. With my examples above, I'd use `ssh -L 192.168.11.41:200:10.0.0.8:200 8.8.8.8` That works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is an obvious error in your command. Your program only runs on the local network, but you are forwarding connection to the public IP using `-L 200:8.8.8.8:200`. So you should use `-L 200:10.0.0.8:200` instead.

Second, by using `-L 200:10.0.0.8:299`, ssh client will only listen on `localhost:200` by default. This behavior can be configured by using the `GatewayPorts` option. To explicitly tell ssh client to accept connection from other hosts you can use `-L 0.0.0.0:10.0.0.8:200`.  From `man ssh_config`:

```
     GatewayPorts
             Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to local forwarded ports.  By default, ssh(1) binds local port forwardings to the loopback address.  This
             prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports.  GatewayPorts can be used to specify that ssh should bind local port forwardings to the wild‐
             card address, thus allowing remote hosts to connect to forwarded ports.  The argument must be yes or no (the default).
```